# How to (1) condense into one row after certain number of rows; (2) How to assign field names

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

Using Pentaho PDI 8.3.

After REST calls with quite complex data structures, I was able to extract data with a row for each data element in a REST result/ E.g:
DataCenterClusterAbstract
1
UK1
Datacenter (auto generated)
Company
29
0
39
15
DATAUPDATEJOB
2016-04-09T21:34:31.18
DataCenterClusterAbstract
2
UK1_Murex
Datacenter (auto generated)
Company
0
0
0
0
DATAUPDATEJOB
2016-04-09T21:34:31.18
DataCenterClusterAbstract
3
UK1_UNIX

Notice that there are 8 data elements that are spread out into separate rows. I would like to condense these 8 data elements into one row each iteration in Pentaho. Is this possible? And assign field names?

Row flattener

Condense 8 data element in columns into one row. Each of these 8 data elements are repeating.

Comment: I tried Row Flattener - it works but doesn't put spaces between fields!

Answer (score 0):

(1) Add row flattener
(2) Assign field names for the rows coming in - so you have 10 data attributes in rows specify a field name for each row.
(3) In table output use space as seperator